# Hover over X or Y to change color of Y only

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm making a navbar that consists of icons followed by the title of their page (e.g. Icon of a home followed by the text 'Home'). Let's say I want to change the color of only(!) the icon from black (default) to blue when hovering over either the text or the icon itself using the :hover selector. How can I do that? (I don't want to use jQuery, just CSS)
The markup is now something like this:

```
<ul id="navbar">
<li class="navgroup">
    <ul>
        <li class="navicon"><i class="icon-home"></i></li>
        <li class="navname">Home</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navgroup">
    <ul>
        <li class="navicon"><i class="icon-info"></i></li>
        <li class="navname">Information</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navgroup">
    <ul>
        <li class="navicon"><i class="icon-contact"></i></li>
        <li class="navname">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Of course everything is `{display:inline}`

Comment: The color of the icon has to change too when you hover over the .navname: 'Home'..

Comment: ul.navgroup:hover > .iconinfo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the hover to the ul inside the navgroups. CSS below does that, you can add whatever styling you like to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/PQShS/9/

CSS:

```
.navgroup ul:hover .navicon{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Your Code

```
<ul id="navbar">
<li class="navgroup">
    <ul>
        <li class="navicon"><i class="icon-home"></i></li>
        <li class="navname">Home</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navgroup">
    <ul>
        <li class="navicon"><i class="icon-info"></i></li>
        <li class="navname">Information</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navgroup">
    <ul>
        <li class="navicon"><i class="icon-contact"></i></li>
        <li class="navname">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank! This is a really simple solution that works for me! I'm using this in combination with the Simple Icon Hover Effects from Codrops (source: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/30/simple-icon-hover-effects/ ).

Answer (score 1):

Since it boils down to changing the look of the icon when the cursor hovers anywhere above the `ul` element, you can do this:

```
.navgroup ul:hover .navIcon .icon-home
{
  /*hover style for the icon*/
}

.navgroup ul .navIcon .icon-home
{
  /*non-hover style for the icon*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following css:

```css
.navgroup:hover .navicon {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

It will modify just the navicon anytime you hover anywhere within the navgroup

## See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/8SNuJ/)

Answer (score 0):

you should use anchor tag

**css:**

```cs
.testing:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

**html:**

```html
<a class="testing" href="">
    <span>hello1</span>
    <span style="color:black;">hell2</span>
</a>
```

Give the whole styling to `<a>` tag and give the inline styling to other element inside `<a>` tag that you don't want to change.